# How to filter out list elements that contain invalid characters in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, conditional-statements

I am writing a function in Python 3.x that will take a list of string variables and a list of valid characters as arguments and return a filtered list containing elements of original list that are made up of valid characters only. I think I can achieve the result using two nested For loops to iterate through list elements and then go through each character of the given element, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to get this result using Python methods or functions.

For the following two lists:

```
valid_characters = ['A','B','C']
my_list = ['abcde','AbCB','ABCBA','XYZ','CBCBB','CABzBAC']
```

The function would return filtered list `['ABCBA','CBCBB']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert `valid_characters` to a set so that you can efficiently determine if a string is made up purely of characters in the set by testing if the set is a superset of the characters in the string:

```
valid_set = set(valid_characters)
print([s for s in my_list if valid_set.issuperset(s)])
```

This outputs:

```
['ABCBA', 'CBCBB']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.